# CodeIgniter query returns -1 rows

Tags: sql-server, codeigniter, select

Trying to do a CodeIgniter database query on a SQL Sever database. I keep getting no results but I noticed that the num_rows field in the query object is -1 (as opposed to 0 if I were actually getting no results). What does this mean? I'm assuming it is trying to report an error but I haven't found any information on it.

Comment: Please post your query and your db schema.

Comment: The query is not the issue. I post the same query with the build in PHP functions and get results.